# MySQL Multiple Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create mysql request to the server I want to retrieve users from the table that as I do not have in friends list.

Here's how I'm trying to learn but I do not receive please help me

```
SELECT
  t1.*, t2.*
FROM
  users as t1,
  friends as t2
WHERE
  t2.user_id='1'
  and t2.fr_id!=t1.id
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: SHow us the tables sructure

Comment: Need to see the table structure.

Comment: @Стефан Симеонов  or you learn SQL or you give us example data on sqlfriddle.. and ask your question better. I understand you want a result off poeple that arn't your friend already or do you want a list off users had have the same friend as you?

Answer (score 0):

The query you want is something like:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM users t1 left outer join
     friends t2
     on t2.fr_id = t1.id and
        t2.user_id = '1'
WHERE t2.user_id is null
ORDER BY RAND();
```

I'm not sure what the `t2.user_id = 1` is doing.  It is not needed if you are looking through the entire friends list.

Comment: t2.user_id=1 (1 is my number for example)

Comment: this not show this what me need, showing my profile and my friends and other users i want to show only users who is no my friends.